# Jwt cannot be parsed, Okta

Tags: javascript, jwt, okta, okta-api

I am trying to set up  Okta authentication on my React App.
On the client side I am able to authenticate successfully and I get the access token. However when I try to authenticate a backend service using OktaJwtVerfier, I get the error message: 
'Jwt cannot be parsed. SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0'

I have develop a very simple test program to test the verification of the token, so basically I get authenticated on the browser, I copy paste the jwt token in my small script to test authentication, and it fails with the message above, what am I doing wrong?

```
const OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier');


const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
    issuer: "https://dev-XXXXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default",
    clientId: "XXXXXX",
    assertClaims: {
        'aud': 'api://default',
        'cid': "XXXXXX",
    },
});


const accessToken = 'Bearer eyJraWQiO.....';


oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(accessToken).then((jwt) => {
    console.log('auth succesfulll', jwt);
}).catch((e)=> {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: you have to start parsing after "Bearer". The JWT start at "eyJ...". "Bearer" is not part of the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by @jps is correct.  Your header has a value of `Bearer XXXX`, where `XXXX` is the actual JWT string to parse.

Here's an example from the Okta project of how they do it in an Express app:

```
const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || '';
const match = authHeader.match(/Bearer (.+)/);
if (!match) {
  res.status(401);
  return next('Unauthorized');
}

const accessToken = match[1];
```

You can see the code in its full context [here.](https://github.com/okta/samples-nodejs-express-4/blob/master/resource-server/server.js#L29)

your code could be modified as follows:

```
const headerValue = 'Bearer eyJraWQiO.....';

const match = headerValue.match(/Bearer (.+)/);
if (!match) {
  throw new Error('your error message here')
}

const accessToken = match[1];

oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(accessToken).then((jwt) => {
  console.log('auth succesfulll', jwt);
}).catch((e)=> {
  console.log(e);
})
```